# double click editable table in AngularJS for each wrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm Angularjs new learner. I modified an existing code example, want to double click to edit each `li`, however, once I added one more, they won't work as I expected.

```
<li ng-dblclick="startEditing(item);">
          <span ng-hide="item.editing">{{item.name}}</span>
          <form ng-submit="doneEditing(item)" ng-show="item.editing">
              <input ng-model="item.name" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-focus="item == editedItem">
          </form>
      </li>

         <li ng-dblclick="startEditing(item);">
          <span ng-hide="item.editing">{{item.thing}}</span>
          <form ng-submit="doneEditing(item)" ng-show="item.editing">
              <input ng-model="item.ting" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-focus="item == editedItem">
          </form>
      </li>
```

I am wondering if `startEditing(item.name);` is better to detect each `li`

http://jsfiddle.net/d9d3hsku/

Is there a simple way to make the field editable but don't need to repeat to paste and modify this bit

```
<form ng-submit="doneEditing(item)" ng-show="item.editing">
              <input ng-model="item.name" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" ng-focus="item == editedItem">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

`ng-focus` is triggered every time you doubleClick on input! because 
of this line :

`ng-focus="item == editedItem"`

and therefore `ng-blure`  is triggered automatically on another

input! So removing it will do the trick:

```
      <li ng-dblclick="startEditing(item);">
          <span ng-hide="item.editing">{{item.name}}</span>
          <form ng-submit="doneEditing(item)" ng-show="item.editing">
              <input ng-model="item.name" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)">
          </form>
      </li>

         <li ng-dblclick="startEditing(item);">
          <span ng-hide="item.editing">{{item.thing}}</span>
          <form ng-submit="doneEditing(item)" ng-show="item.editing">
              <input ng-model="item.thing" ng-blur="doneEditing(item)" >
          </form>
      </li>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vahidahmad/bppkyn38/) is Jsfiddle for it!

You can use [angular-xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) as @Rishab777 answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [directive](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) it might be helpful.